# What objects can be placed in a cube container with a length of 1 meter?

Tags: graphics3d

What objects can be placed in a cube container with a length of 1 meter? The thickness of the container wall is negligible

1. A sphere with a diameter of 0.99 meters
2. Tetrahedra with all edges of 1.4 meters in length
3. A cylinder with a bottom diameter of 0.01 meters and a height of 1.8 meters
4. A cylinder with a bottom diameter of 1.2 meters and a height of 0.01 meters

I drew a cube with an edge length of 1 meter：

```
Clear["Global`*"];
c = {0, 0, 0};
d = {1, 0, 0};
b = {0, 1, 0};
a = b + d;
h = 1;
c1 = {0, 0, h};
d1 = d + c1
a1 = a + c1
b1 = b + c1
labels = {Text[Style[A, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style[B, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[C, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c, {1, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d, {-2, 0}], 
   Text[Style[A1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], a1, {3, 0}], 
   Text[Style[B1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], b1, {-1, -2}], 
   Text[Style[C1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], c1, {0, 1}], 
   Text[Style[D1, 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], d1, {3, 0}]};
dashLines = {Dashed, 
   AbsoluteThickness[2], {Red, Line[{{c, d}, {c, c1}, {b, c}}]}};
realLines = {AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   Line[{{a, b}, {a, d}, {d, d1}, {b, b1}, {a1, a}, {b, b1}, {b1, 
      a1}, {b1, c1}, {c1, d1}, {a1, d1}}]};
Show[Graphics3D[{dashLines, realLines, labels}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {2, 3.5, 1.28}], 
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{c1, c1 + {0, 0, 1}}, {d, d + {1, 0, 0}}, {b, 
      b + {0, 1, 0}}}], 
   Text[Style["z", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    c1 + {0, 0, 1}, {-1, -1}], 
   Text[Style["y", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    b + {0, 1, 0}, {-2, -1}], 
   Text[Style["x", 20, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
    d + {1, 0, 0}, {2, -1}]}]]
```

How can we determine if the four objects mentioned above can be placed in this cubic container with an edge length of one meter?

Solution:

Since the diameter of the Inscribed sphere of a cube with a 1 m edge length is 1 m, the first option is correct.

Since Regular tetrahedron with edge length of Sqrt [2] m can be placed in a cube with edge length of 1m, and Sqrt [2]>1.4, the second option is correct.

Due to the fact that the diagonal length of a cube with an edge length of 1m is Sqrt [3] m and Sqrt [3]<1.8, a cylinder with a height of 1.8m cannot be placed in a cube container. The third option is incorrect.

Since the length of the cube diagonal with the edge length of 1 m is Sqrt [3] m, and the height of 0.01 m of the cylinder with the bottom diameter of 1.2 m can be ignored, it is only necessary to place the bottom of the cylinder in parallel with the cube diagonal, that is, it can be placed in the cube container as a whole, so the fourth option is correct.

Comment: Are you are allowing objects to be rotated? For example, a long thin object could fit if it was rotated to align with the hypotenuse of the cube but might be too big otherwise. Do you just want a solution for these four objects, or something more general, as that problem is somewhat harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I present an approach which gives maximal sphere  and maximal thetrahedron:

```
cube = Graphics3D[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Blue], Cube[]} ,Boxed -> False]
```

sphere

```
sphere = NMaximize[{r, RegionWithin[Cube[], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r] ]}, r](*{0.5, {r -> 0.5}}*)
Show[{cube, Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]]} /. sphere[[2]]]
```

[image]

Maximal radius `r->0.5`!

tetrahedron

```
pts = Table[{x[i], y[i], z[i]}, {i, 1, 4}];
tetra = NMaximize[{Volume[Tetrahedron[pts ]],RegionMember[cub, pts ] }, Flatten[pts]]
Show[cube, Graphics3D[{ Tetrahedron[pts ]} /. tetra[[2]]]]
```

[image]

Maximal sidelength `1.4142`

```
Norm[pts[[1]] - pts[[2]]] /. tetra[[2]] (* Sqrt[2] *)
```